# Как написать код что бы по кнопке воспроизводилась анимация с шансом 10% 90% нечего не происходилою

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть кнопка. Она считает клики по ней. Но мне нужно что бы с каким то шансом при каждом клике проигрывалась анимация выпадения сундука. Вот этот код не работает. он с вероятностью в 10% вырубает кнопку(она перестает нажиматься и считать клики. Возможно я что то в самой юнити начудил. Есть анимация AnimCheats, аниматор AnimCheats. В аниматоре start -> пустая анимация -> AnimCheats через тригер Play.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{    
    [SerializeField] int money;
    public Text moneyText;
    public Animation anim;
    public AnimationClip a;

    private void Start() 
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");  
    }   

        
    public void ButtonClick() 
    {
        money++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money",money);
        if (Random.Range(1.0f, 100.0f) > 90)
        { anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
        
            anim.Play("Play");
        }
    }
    public void ToAch() 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        moneyText.text = money.ToString();      
    }
     
}
```

Comment: А анимация то проигрывается?

Comment: нет не проигрывается

Answer (score 0):

Решил так

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{    
    [SerializeField] int money;
    [SerializeField] int chest;
    public Text moneyText;
    public Text chestText;
    public Animator anim;



    private void Start() 
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");
        chest = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("chest");

    }
      
    public void ButtonClick() 
    {
        money++;
       
        float x = Random.Range(1f, 101f);

        if (x <= 5f)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Play");
            chest++;

        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money",money);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("chest",chest);

    }
    public void ToAch() 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        moneyText.text = money.ToString(); 
        chestText.text = chest.ToString();
    }
     
}
```